# Pulling a specific character from a list SML

Tags: smlnj

Hello im still relatively new to SML/NJ and im struggling to figure out how I can pull a specific character from a tuple list, I was told that you explode the string then pull the specific value by calling it but calling the value is what im having issues with if anybody can help me with this I'd appreciate it.

**Here the code :**

```
val test = ("abcdefg", 3);
```

explode (#1 test):

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I never have gotten an error from the code listed above its more so me not knowing how to pull a specific character once I explode the string if that clears things up a bit.

Comment: I see. Disclaimer, I've never used this language, but it seems that the `explode` function takes a string and returns a list of characters. Could you then use one of the functions on this page to get the character you want: https://smlfamily.github.io/Basis/list.html ?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out I'll update my post whenever I get the chance